# Compress of bitmap doesnt work to reduce PDF File size

Tags: java, android

```
try {

            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument();
            for (int i = 0; i < imageUris.size(); i++) {


                InputStream inStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageUris.get(i));
                Bitmap original = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inStream);
                ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                original.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));


                PdfDocument.PageInfo pageInfo = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), (i + 1)).create();
                PdfDocument.Page page = pdfDocument.startPage(pageInfo);
                Canvas canvas = page.getCanvas();
                Paint paint = new Paint();
                paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), true);
                canvas.drawPaint(paint);
                canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null);
                pdfDocument.finishPage(page);
                bitmap.recycle();
            }
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(GalleryImage.this);
            progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            progressDialog.show();

            pdfDocument.writeTo(fileOutputStream);
            pdfDocument.close();
            Toast.makeText(this, "PDf Created Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            progressDialog.dismiss();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

imageUris is a ArrayList Of image, I tried to compress bitmap of image size so that I can reduce pdf file size. But always pdf size increase 10 times to file size. Compress bitmap size doesn't work.

Any solution how can I reduce my Pdf Size? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Again no full info. What are you comparing? Ten times more? Then what was the size in bytes of the file first? Which file? And what is the size now? And where is the code to generate the small file? We dont know what you do or compare. And compressing a bitmap to a jpg is something different as compressing a file to a zip for instance.

Comment: "I tried to compress bitmap of image size so that I can reduce pdf file size" -- you are not compressing anything. The size of a `Bitmap` is based purely on the resolution and the bit depth of the image. Your `original` `Bitmap` and your `bitmap` `Bitmap` have the same resolution and the same bit depth. Please understand that `PdfDocument` is designed to create PDF documents for *printing*, where size rarely matters. You may need to look into alternative PDF generators (e.g., iText), where you have more control.

Answer (score -2):

When compressing your JPEG image, the quality range is from 0 - 100, where:

0 = MAX Compression (Least Quality which is suitable for Small images)

100 = Least Compression (MAX Quality which is suitable for Big images)

Since you are using `100` at:

```
original.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
```

You'll have to change the 100 and set it to a lower value.